# Visual Studio auto complete is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

A few days ago I started learning Unity and the tutorial I was seeing suggested to download Visual Studio for the C# editor (I have never used Visual Studio before).

After watching some more, I noticed that when he typed something, and VS would show him what he can write but it wasn't doing that for me.

For example he typed `ForceMode.` and a list appeared that had Acceleration, Force, Impulse, VelocityChange.

I have tried everything I found online and it didn't work I also reinstalled it.

P.S. I have downloaded Unity tools.

Comment: The autocomplete is called intellisense... maybe you can use that term to search on the net.

Comment: Here's a possible [solution](https://forum.unity.com/threads/intellisense-not-working-with-visual-studio-fix.836599/) to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Within Unity, ensure that your external script editor is set to visual studio.

You can find this setting under Edit > Preferences > External Tools

For some reason visual studio won't connect with unity correctly unless that option is set

Answer (score 0):

If you see the "Miscellaneous Files" writen like the image below it means that the script is not connected to the project and therefore you don't have the auto complete.

You can see how to solve this problem here

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1585929/miscellaneous-files-making-scripts-not-work.html

[image]